# Partner Community User, Partner Community Login User vs System administrator

Tags: community, partner-communities, system-admin

what is the difference between the Partner Community and Partner Community Login licenses and profiles vs System administrator licenses and profiles. Can anyone please share me Urls

Answer (score 6):

Refer [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5)

> Partner Community License:

A Community member-based license works like a standard Salesforce internal license: external users with a member-based license are able to access a community as many times as they want. The only difference is that external users do not have access to the internal org. Login-based licenses are a bit different.

> Partner Community Login licenses

You first purchase a specific number of logins to be used every month. External users associated with that license consume one login each time they log into a community. However, logging in multiple times during the same day still only consumes one login and, once logged in, switching between communities doesn’t consume extra logins. This type of login is referred to as a daily unique login.

The ration between the number of monthly logins you purchase and the number of login licenses that are provisioned in your org is 1 to 20. For example, if you purchase 1,000 monthly logins, then 20,000 login licenses are provisioned in your org. If you want to assign more than 20,000 login licenses, purchase more logins.

One last point: the timeout period for a session is configurable up to a maximum of 24 hours.

btw, both of those licenses access same feature of Partner Community, e.g. Leads, Opportunities, Campaigns.

> System Administrator profiled users are of Salesforce license.

Designed for users who require full access to standard CRM and Salesforce AppExchange apps. Users with this user license are entitled to access any standard or custom app.